# How convert generic or rawtypes List to a String array

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, raw-types

I am making a List of generic or rawtypes data and trying to store it in a String array, but it is failing with -

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException

here is the code snippet, here in the function I am trying to convert rawtypes to string array but facing above given array, Please if you can take the below given example and guide me what I am doing wrong here  -

```
 public class Parsing {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

            //List<JsonGen> jsongenShow = null;
            String url1 = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/radish/v20/dol/home/carousels/shows.json";
            List[] nwDetails = getShowNWdetailsParser(jsongenShow, url1);

        }


        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public static List[] getShowNWdetailsParser (List<JsonGen> jsongenShow, String url ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
        {
            URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
            ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
            jsongenShow = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<JsonGen>>() {});
            List [] shows = new List [jsongenShow.size()]; 

             String[] showsArr = new String[jsongenShow.size()];
             showsArr= (String[])jsongenShow.toArray(showsArr);

            for (int i=0; i == jsongenShow.size(); i++ ){

                System.out.println(showsArr[i]);
            }
int i = 0;
        for(JsonGen element : jsongenShow) {
            shows[i]=element.getNetworks();

            i++;
            }
        for(int j =0; j<shows.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(showsArr[j]);

        }


            return shows;   
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The problem is the line `showsArr= (String[])jsongenShow.toArray(showsArr);`. You cannot do that because a `JsonGen` is not a `String`. How do you want to convert a `JsonGen` to a `String`?

Comment: I want to process the list as string in some functions accept only string array. I how to cast JsonGen as string?

Comment: @Shek don't cast it to String - if it's not a String then you'll need to convert it to one to store it in a `List<String>`. Most classes have a `toString` method.

Comment: This code doesn't have much sense.  jsongenShow (null) is passed from main but discarded in the called function, and that function returns an array of lists (!) full of nulls. Oh, my!

Comment: @Raffaele I have removed few lines from the given code  /*int i = 0;
  for(JsonGen element : jsongenShow) {
   shows[i++]=element.getNetworks();
   }
  for(int j =0; j<shows.length;j++)
  {
   System.out.println(shows[j]);
   
  }*/

Comment: showsArr[i] = jsongenShow_1.get(i).toString(); is bringing hash values featureshows.JsonGen@4590c9c3
featureshows.JsonGen@32e6e9c3
featureshows.JsonGen@5056dfcb
featureshows.JsonGen@6574b225
featureshows.JsonGen@2669b199
featureshows.JsonGen@2344fc66
featureshows.JsonGen@458ad742
featureshows.JsonGen@5afa04c
featureshows.JsonGen@6ea12c19
featureshows.JsonGen@6a024a67
featureshows.JsonGen@7921b0a2

Answer (score 0):

Java can't automatically convert objects to String for you. You have to loop over the source list and fill the destination array, and map JsonGen to String by yourself.

It's very unfortunate that the APIs allow your code to compile at all

Answer (score 0):

After some experiment , I finally found the way to do it.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static String[] getShowNWdetailsParser (List<JsonGen> jsongenShow, String url ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
        ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<JsonGen> jsongenShow_1 = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<JsonGen>>() {});
        List [] shows = new List [jsongenShow_1.size()]; 
        String[] showsArr = new String[jsongenShow_1.size()];
        for(JsonGen element : jsongenShow_1) {
            shows[i]=element.getNetworks();
            showsArr[i]=shows[i].toString();
            i++;
            }
        for(int j =0; j<shows.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(showsArr[j]);

        }

        return showsArr;    
    }
```